# Combine two very similar ruby if statements

Tags: ruby, regex, string, methods, match

Right now I am finding a match in a string of text:

```
if w.include? 'syn'
    w.sub!(/.*?syn\|/, '')
    return w unless similar?(word, w)
elsif w.include? 'sim'
    w.sub!(/.*?sim\|/, '')
    return w unless similar?(word, w)
end
```

But I want to be able to combine them, something like what I did in another little program (this is just a snippet of it):

```
def plus
    self.meta_reduce(:+)
end 

def minus
    self.meta_reduce(:-)
end 

def times
    self.make_float
    self.meta_reduce(:*)
end 

def divide
    self.make_float
    self.meta_reduce(:/)
end 

def make_float args = nil 
    return args.to_f if args
    @value = @value.map {|n| n.to_f }
end 

def meta_reduce operation = :sym
    if @value.length < 2 
        raise 'calculator is empty'
    end 
    @value = self.push(@value.pop(2).reduce(operation))
end
```

I know that in my math example, the difference in methods is the operation being applied, and in the other, the difference would be what is being matched. Is there an elegant way to create a new method on the fly just by feeding the substring?

Comment: What exactly do you mean combine them? I can't follow what you want to do.

Comment: I think when he is saying *combine* he really means *refactor*

Comment: Yes, I meant refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be compacted a lot as it stands if you realise that `string.sub!(/xxx/, '')` will do nothing and return `nil` if `string` doesn't contain `xxx`. So you can write

```
if w.sub!(/.*?syn\|/, '') or w.sub!(/.*?sim\|/, '')
  return w unless similar?(word, w)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
%w[syn sim].each do |str|
  if w.include? str
    w.sub!(/.*?#{str}\|/, '')
    return w unless similar?(word, w)
  end
end
```